# How does IEEE 754 floating-point represent numbers much larger than the significand?

Tags: floating-point, computer-science

I am a novice and I am feeling like a nitwit right now. I apologize for any ignorant statements or inaccuracies in advance.  For the past two days I have been racking my brain against floating point numbers and I have yet to feel like I truly understand them. Right now, I am stumped on the *perceived* incongruity between the the number of mantissa bits and the range the exponent bits are able to represent. I will reiterate some basics to illustrate my confusion:

- In IEEE 754 32-bit floating there is 1 sign bit, 8 exponent bits, and
  24 significand bits
- Similar to decimal-base scientific notation, the significand is multiplied by the base-2 exponent in order to shift the radix point
  to the desired location, i.e 1.00 * 2^3 -> 100(4).
- -IEEE 754 uses the 8-bit exponent allocation to represent values from 2^-126 to 2^127, ignoring non(sub?)-normalized exceptions.

If all one is doing by multiplying the significand by the exponent is shifting the radix-point,  it *seems* like the maximum shift possible/ is 24 bits i.e from 1.00...0000 to 100...0000 and therefore the maximum value is 2^24. But this is no different from 32-bit integer formats and the exponent range indicates otherwise. According to h-schmidt.net, (https://www.h-schmidt.net/FloatConverter/IEEE754.html) 1.111111111111111111111111 * 2^127 (the maximum value) is "actually stored in float" as 340282346638528859811704183484516925440, a number far larger than 24 bits would allow for.

This leads me to believe, and this is probably obvious, that a given float is stored as the elements (sign, exp., mant.) of a product and the the actual value or product is only displayed when it is "called". If that is the case, where is that product stored when I see it on my screen? If I only have 32/24? bits but the number outputted is larger than 32 bits where is that larger number being stored? What is actually happening and where is the gap in my understanding?

Any response would be greatly appreciated and my thanks in advance.

Comment: "...and 23 significand bits" --> more like 24 significant bits: 1 is implied and 23 are encoded.

Comment: Thank you chux, will make that correction.

Comment: In decimal, when you write 9.87 * 10 to the 12th power, you encode 5 decimal digits 98712, yet the value 9,870,000,000,000 is more than the 5 digit 99,999.  Same applies to [float32](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-precision_floating-point_format). Is that sufficient?  Consider what _float_ means with these scientific notation like numbers.

Comment: What I am confused about is where the larger number is stored. If I have a maximum of 32 bits allocated but my number is larger than 32 bits as in the example in my post, "where"  is that larger number when I see it outputted to the terminal. I am sure that question is somehow silly but please bear with me.

Comment: Only the leading digits of that large number are stored.  Like "9.87 * 10 to the 12th power", we do not need to store 13 digits (9870000000000), just 5 (98712) - we interpret those digits differently, as 9.78*(10 to the 12th), not as 98,712.

Comment: Thank you again for responding chux. What I still do not understand is that after multiplying the signifcand by the exponent I have a number like 9,870,000,000,000. My assumption so far is that there is a one bit to one digit correspondence when the number is outputted on the terminal. If we assume that 9.87 * 10^12 is part of a 5-bit encoding scheme, where is the computer putting 9,870,000,000,000 (13 digits and therefore 13 bits). 13 > 5. What am I missing?

Comment: I suspect this approach is not working, sorry if I added confusion.  I hope others can provide a clear answer.

Comment: All bits of the number are not stored anywhere.  If you add 2 numbers like (1 x 2 ^ 200)  + (1 x 2^0) the result is just (1 x 2 ^ 200) and the +1 has no effect because there are not 200 significant digits.  This might help: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating-point_arithmetic  When the terminal displays a large (or very small) number it either uses scientific notation, or the trailing or leading zeros are added by knowing the exponent -- if you have 1 x (10 ^ 1000) and want to print it you don't need to store a 1,000 digit number anywhere you can just print "0" 999 times.

Comment: "Value actually stored in float" means (on that webpage) "decimal representation of the value which is actually stored". The actually stored value is `+1.111111111111111111111111 * 2^127`, where the `+` is stored as `0`, the leading `1.` is not stored, and the exponent is stored as `11111110` (binary). When a (decimal) number is outputted on a terminal, a conversion needs to happen (which is a different non-trivial problem).

Comment: There is no "one bit to one digit" correspondence.  Floating-point numbers are 100% binary, 0% decimal.  Consider the decimal number 3458764513820540928.  It's got 19 digits, and in straight (integer) binary it's 62 bits.  But it just happens to be 3 × 2⁶⁰, so it's perfectly representable as a float, since the significand only requires two bits, and we've got 24 to play with.  It's got a significand of `0b1.1`, and a biased exponent of 0xbc = 188 - 127 = 61.  The number of bits in the actual significand (two) versus the full number (62) is covered by the fact that those bits are all 0.

Comment: As for where the extra digits "come from" when they're printed, they literally spring into existence somewhere down inside the output routines.  There are always translations like that going on, especially during i/o.  If internally the binary number is `101`, and it gets printed as "5", where did the character "5" come from?  The integer-to-string code generated it.  And when you're doing floating-point-to-string conversion, you end up generating lots of digits that weren't explicitly there (in the internal bitpattern being converted and printed) at all.

Comment: This is hard to think about at first, especially for floating point.  We imagine that the variables in our computer programs "contain" numbers, and we imagine that when we print the variables out, what we see is what the variables contain.  But in actual fact there are multiple levels of translation going on.  Underneath the value "5" that I see is the binary number 00000101, and underneath that binary number are some electrical signals on an integrated circuit.  So what "is" my variable?  It's convenient and usually accurate to say "5", but there's more going on underneath.

Comment: And, as I said, it's even trickier for floating point, because what you see and think about in decimal is increasingly divorced from what's actually internally represented.  My example 3 × 2⁶⁰ is `0b1.1` × 2⁶¹ internally, and if we printed it in full hexadecimal it'd be 3000000000000000 (where many of those 0's got generated during printing), and if we printed it in decimal we'd get 3458764513820540928 again, where all 19 of those random-looking digits were generated (again during printing) from the much simpler internal representation `0b1.1` × 2⁶¹.

Comment: Once you've digested that, for extra credit think about setting a variable to 0.1, and having it be stored internally as `0x1.99999a` × 2⁻⁴, and having it printed back out again as 0.10000000149.

Comment: Small note: `1.111111111111111111111111 * 2^127` is not correct: the significand has only 23 bits after the implied leading 1, you have put 24 trailing 1s after the fraction separator, that's one too much.

Answer (score 2):

In case you're being mentally tripped up by having to convert between binary and decimal, it may be helpful to consider a hypothetical *decimal* computer (henceforth “HDC”).

Suppose that one HDC machine word has just enough capacity to store two `+`/`-` signs (one for the number, and one for the exponent), plus nine digits.  The standard `float` format on this computer uses a form of scientific notation, allocating 7 digits to the significand, and 2 to the exponent, such that the machine word `±ABCDEFG±HI` represents the number ±A.BCDEFG × 10<sup>±HI</sup>.

For example, [Avogadro's number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Avogadro_constant) 6.02214076×10<sup>23</sup> would be stored in the HDC format as `+6022141+23`, rounded to 7 significant digits.

It's clear that the largest possible HDC `float` value is 9.999999×10<sup>99</sup>, stored as `+9999999+99`.  If written out in full, this would be a 100-digit number (7 `9`'s followed by 93 `0`'s).  But we don't actually *store* the 100 digits anywhere, just the `+9999999+99`.

Now, while it's *possible* to make a programming language that stores all numbers in floating-point (e.g., JavaScript), it's often more convenient, efficient, or accurate to have a dedicated separate type for storing just whole numbers or “integers”.  Most languages call this type `int`.  Like a real computer, HDC provides instructions to do arithmetic on `int` numbers.  The standard `int` format simply ignores the second sign symbol in a machine word, and uses all 9 digits to represent a numeric value.

The largest `int` value on the HDC is `+999999999`.  In scientific notation, this is 9.99999999×10<sup>8</sup>.  As a consequence, **HDC `float` values with an exponent of 9 or higher cannot be represented as an `int`**.  But this is not a serious problem for doing arithmetic, as long as you use `float` instead of `int` for any variables that require the out-of-`int` range.

Now, let's consider the problem of how the HDC *displays* numbers to a user in text form.

For `int` values, this is straightforward: Just display the exact decimal digits that are stored in-memory, but omit the leading sign if it's `+`, and omit leading `0` characters (except when all 9 digits are `0`, in which case display one `0`).  This is *much* easier than on a binary computer where you have to do math to convert binary to decimal.

For `float` values, we can break down the printing algorithm into:

1. If the number is negative, print `-`, then negate the number (giving a positive number).
2. Print the integer part of the number.
3. Print a `.` character.
4. Print the requested number of digits to the right of the decimal point.

Steps 1 and 3 are trivial.  Step 4 is also pretty straightforward.

```c
// x = number to print (0.0 <= x < 1.0)
// decimal_places = number of decimal places to use
void print_decimal_fraction(float x, int decimal_places)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < decimal_places; ++i)
    {
        x *= 10;
        int digit = (int) x;
        putchar('0' + digit);
        x -= digit;
    }
}
```

The hard part is Step 2.  A naïve approach is to just pass `(int) x` to the routine that prints an `int`.  But, as you mention in your question, we need to handle larger numbers.

**But this can be easily solved with just a bit of recursion.**

```c
void print_int_part(float x)
{
    if (x < 10)
    {
        // Just a one-digit number.
        putchar('0' + (int) x);
    }
    else
    {
        // Print all but the last digit.
        print_int_part(floor(x / 10));
        // Print the last digit.
        print_int_part(fmod(x, 10));
    }
}
```

All we need from the floating-point hardware is the ability to divide by 10 (and get the remainder), and convert *small* (single-digit) `float` values to `int`.  **We never need to store the theoretical 100 left-of-the decimal digits in one variable.**  Just work with them one at a time.

Also note that **the above algorithm does not depend on the numbers being *stored* in base ten**.  It's more efficient if they are, since then multiplication or division by 10.0 is just shifting the exponent.  But you *can* use the same digit-by-digit approach on binary computers.

Comment: Nicely explained.  I like your "HDC", and the point that "the algorithm does not depend on the numbers being stored in base ten".  Indeed, the algorithm doesn't care *what* the representation is: all it depends on is that the processor it's running on can perform mathematical operations like `*`, `/`, `fmod`, and `floor` on that representation (whatever it is). (Of course, a high-quality implementation would have to worry about properly rounding the result, and guarding against any cascading precision loss involved in all those all those multiplications and divisions.)

Comment: @SteveSummit: Well, yeah.  If you're astute, you can see that my `print_decimal_fraction` truncates instead of rounds.

Answer (score 1):

> This leads me to believe... that a given float is stored as the elements (sign, exp., mant.) of a product and the the actual value or product is only displayed when it is "called". If that is the case, where is that product stored when I see it on my screen?

Yes, floating-point formats are a compact way of representing "big" numbers.  You could even think of a floating-point format as a form of compression.  And, yes, when you take such a representation and "uncompress" it so that you can, for example, display it on your screen, it's only during the uncompression process (that is, the formatting or printing process) that the redundant information is made explicit.

For example, we can consider the famous number [Googol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Googol), or 10<sup>100</sup>, or 1 with 100 zeros.  We can represent that in scientific notation as 1 × 10<sup>100</sup>, or in computer programming "E" notation as `1E100`.  Those notations have 7 and 5 characters, respectively, but if we want to see the "full" number it's 10000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000, which has 101 characters.  Where did all those extra 0's come from?  How can we store 101 characters' worth of information in just 5 or 7 characters?  And the answers are, (1) scientific notation is a representation that lets us represent large numbers, albeit with reduced precision (meaning that we could *not* have used 5-7 characters to represent an arbitrary 101-digit number), and (2) the "extra" 0's only appeared when someone — in this case me — applied an algorithm to convert the compact notation 1 × 10<sup>100</sup> into the much longer 100…000 form.

But the other thing to notice is that scientific or exponential notation doesn't just count 0's; that is, it's not just another form of [run-length encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Run-length_encoding).  Exponential notation is a mathematical operation, and we can especially see this if we start working in mixed bases.

Let's consider a number we might call a "binary Googol", that is, 1 with one hundred 0's after it, but in base 2.  That's the number 1 × 2<sup>100</sup>, or in the "hex float" notation used by some programming languages, `0x1P100`.  If we "expand" it to a full-length binary number we of course get 1000…000<sub>2</sub> (where I've skipped a few of the digits), and that's the same sort of thing we saw for the decimal Googol.  But what if we take our "binary Googol" and print it in base 10?  It's 1267650600228229401496703205376, and that might be an even more surprising result!  Again, we seemed to get a lot more information out: 6-7 characters somehow expanded to 31.  But now they're not all 0!  All the digits are different!  Does that mean we've discovered a magic way to compress any 31-digit number down to just 6-7 characters?

And the answer is, "No, we have not".  The digits in that particular 31-digit number 1267650600228229401496703205376 are not random; they just happen to be the exact decimal representation of 2<sup>100</sup>.  They were generated, deterministically, by mathematical operations starting with a value of 1 × 2<sup>100</sup>, or `0x1P100`.  Although the decimal number 1267650600228229401496703205376 just happens to have this nicely compact binary exponential representation, nearby numbers like 1267650600228229401496703205375 or 1267650600228229401496703205377 would not.

---

Addendum: Most programming languages have some way of converting an *integer* in its internal, usually binary, representation into a *string*.  And when you call such a function, you may have to think about how big that string might be — because the integer-to-string function is precisely the spot where we stop caring about the size of the internal representation in bytes (e.g. 4 bytes for a 32-bit integer) and start caring about the number of printable characters in the human-readable output form.  For example, a 32-bit integer might take 10, 11, 13, or more characters to print in decimal, depending on whether we also needed a leading minus sign, or internal commas for readability.
(The representation "-2,147,483,648" is 14 characters long.)  In programming languages like C, which don't have a first-class built-in string type, trying to predict how big an output buffer you'll need to hold the result of a given integer-to-string conversion turns out to be an interesting and bug-prone problem.

But that's just for integers.  What about a function that converts a *floating point* number to a printable, human-readable string representation?  How big an output buffer might you need for that?  Single-precision floating point can hold numbers up to about 3.4 × 10<sup>38</sup>, and double-precision can go up to 1.8 × 10<sup>308</sup>.  So you might need more than 300 characters to represent the largest double-precision value — and that's just the integer part.  What about the fractional part?  Those can get bulky, too.  The smallest normalized double-precision fraction is a number that works out to about 2.225 × 10<sup>-308</sup>, and if you try to print that exactly you get a number like 0.000…00002225073858…, where the first … stands for three hundred 0's I left out, and the second … stands for a whole bunch more random-looking digits — although they aren't really random; they're just the decimal expansion of the fraction 1 / 2<sup>1022</sup>.  In fact, it's no coincidence that the full decimal expansion of 1 / 2<sup>1022</sup> has a total of 1022 digits to the right of the decimal point, or in other words, the decimal expansion of a double-precision floating-point number (which is 8 bytes internally) might require a cool kilobyte of output space.

Comment: Hmm, the minimal exponent applies to the implied leading bit of the significand. The corresponding exponent of trailing bit of significand is 52 places further, that is -1074. You would thus need 1074 places for printing the fraction part of small double precisions. 5^1074 requires 751 decimal digits to be printed, thus smallest denormalized has 323 leading zeros in fraction part, followed by 751 decimals digits.

Comment: But you can get an even longer decimal part if you print (2^53-1)*(2^-1074), that's 307 leading zeroes for the fraction part, followed by 767 decimal digits. That may explain why we usually do not print the exact representation of floating point, but rather an approximate one. Either rounding to a fixed number of digits, or rounding to the shortest representation that would convert back to same float according to default ot current rounding direction

Comment: Another consideration for printing floats is that those trailing decimals have low significance: indeed, in the most extreme case, smallest denormalized has only 1 bit of precision. That's less than 1 decimal digit... Thus evaluating double d=1.0e-324 and 2.0e-324 should round to zero, while 3.0e-324 to 7.0e-324 should all round to smallest denormalized. 8.0e-324 and 9.0e-324 should round to next denormalized (that's twice the min). So the next 750 decimals do not account for much... They are just artifacts of conversion from base 2 to base 10, somehow.